# Logic exercise - Help!

Tags: logic

The exercise is the following. I had a rough time thinking about it and want some help.

We have this group of 520 people. You know that, from this people:

- 350 don't listen to radio
- 90 don't listen to radio nor watch tv
- 110 only listen to radio.

So, how many people watch tv **and** listen to radio ? How can you explain your reply.

Our reply was: If 350 don't listen to radio AND 90 don't listen to radio nor watch tv, you only, the remaining number is 80.

So, given the data, only 80 people **might** listen to radio AND watch tv.

Im not sure completely sure about the reply. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** There are four groups: A only listens to radio, B only watches TV, C does both, D does neither. The 350 who don't listen to radio are groups B and D. So you have $$A+B+C+D=520\\B+D=350\\D=90\\A=110$$

Comment: A really good idea, but we are not able yet to figure it out. We guess some data is missing. Is it possible with the current data to know the answer?

Comment: Start from the bottom. You have $A$ and $D$, find $B$, then $C$. That is your answer

Answer (score 0):

Here is the problem

> Our reply was: If 350 don't listen to radio AND 90 don't listen to radio nor watch tv, you only, the remaining number is 80.

Why are you adding these two? It's clear that any person who does NOT listen to the radio nor watches tv also falls into the category of a person that does not listen to radio. Andrei's answer is correct, maybe try to draw the different groups in a Venn diagram so you can see it more clearly.